# TO in cleft sentences

Tags: clefts

Can anyone explain me why we sometimes have TO in cleft sentences in the second part of the sentence and sometimes don't?

*E.g.

- What I'd really love to do is Ø go hang gliding once in my life.
- What she wishes she had done is Ø find a job nearer home.
- All I've ever wanted to do is TO work with endangered species.*

Comment: I don't understand why you seem to imply that the alternatives would be incorrect: "What I'd really love to do is TO go hang gliding once in my life." "What she wishes she had done is TO have found a job nearer home." "All I've ever wanted to do is X work with endangered species."

Comment: Your third example does not have a cleft structure. It is two noun phrases linked by "is". Those noun phrases may be swapped, but there is no cleaving or joining involved. Cf. All you need is love <---> Love is all you need.

Comment: There is, mostly, no _why_ in syntax, only what is or is not admissible. Exceptions and parallel constructions abound.

Comment: Thank you so much! No forum could provide an answer so quickly! As I see it now: we can either use or omit TO in the second part of cleft sentences, it's just the matter of choice. This question has been bothering me for such a long time,I'm finally relieved!

Comment: That's not the whole story. Some verbs resist/bar to-deletion: 'What they are really trying to accomplish is to deny any coverage to any woman who gets an abortion ...'. // 'I think the best thing I can hope to achieve is to educate, or make aware, as many people as possible on how the little things they do every day really do affect our environment.' [[Aaron Peirsol; Picture Quotes](http://www.picturequotes.com/i-think-the-best-thing-i-can-hope-to-achieve-is-to-educate-or-make-aware-as-many-people-as-possible-quote-684563) (the first 'to', I'd say, cannot be deleted, but covers 'make aware'.)

Comment: ... Note that switching 'accomplish' or 'achieve' to 'do' makes the to-deleted version sound far more acceptable.